# Using Variable In JSON node.js

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I am writing some code that allows me to send messages back and forth from two node instances using HTTP & Express.

Each client generates a UUID type of identification and then sends it to the main server for storage and authentication.

Here is the client, you can see at the bottom that it generates what i beleive to be a json string,  i assign a variable before that contains an ID, i am trying to use this ID to send to the server for proccessing.

Client.js

```
var request = require('request');
var sendservlet = request.post;
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path'); 
var crypto = require('crypto');

if (fs.existsSync('foo.txt')) {
    console.log('Found ');
    fs.readFile('foo.txt', "utf-8" ,  function (err, data) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log(data);
});

} else {
    console.log("Did not find file, i must first register you to the server.");
    function randomValueHex (len) {
    return crypto.randomBytes(Math.ceil(len/2))
        .toString('hex') 
        .slice(0,len);   
}
var ID = randomValueHex(7)
console.log("Your New Identification Number Is: " + ID);

sendservlet(
    'http://192.168.1.225:3000',
    { form: { key: ID } },
    function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            console.log(body)
            console.log(ID)
        }
    }
);
}
```

Server.JS

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
var crypto = require('crypto');

app.post('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('POST request to the homepage');
console.log(req.body.form.key);
});

var server = app.listen(3000, function () {
  var host = server.address().address;
  var port = server.address().port;

  console.log('Example app listening at http://%s:%s', host, port);
});
```

The server cannot seem to be able to read it, i believe that i cannot call the variable like that.

To help narrow this issue down, I am strictly asking why the ID variable cannot be transmitted in

```
sendservlet(
        'http://192.168.1.225:3000',
        { form: { key: ID } },
```

thank you very much for any advice available!

Comment: Install Wireshark and look at the packets that are sent between client and server. That will be very illuminating, because your core problem is this part: *"it generates what i beleive to be a json string"*

Comment: What do you see when you do `console.log(req.body)` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `console.log(req.body.form.key);`, you just want `console.log(req.body.key);`

The `form` key is just what `request` uses for (basically) "This is my form data, so this is the stuff to POST to the URL." Whatever was in `form` on the `request` side just gets put into `req.body` on the `express` side. So you want `req.body.key`.